# CSS Footer Columns not displaying Correctly

Tags: css

I'm new to css and stuck and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. But I would like to have the foot show as three columns. If you look at the image layout and notice the footer has three columns well that's the i'm trying to achieve. Also the footer dotted lines show past the layout.

Here is my layout: http://gdisinc.com/barker/images/menubar/layout_barker.jpg

Here is the working site: http://www.gdisinc.com/barker/default.php#

Could you tell me what I have to do to fix it. Let me know if you have any questions?

Comment: Can you paste the relevant html/css (footer stuff) into a jsfiddle.net example for us please? :)

Comment: I neither understand the question nor the problem.

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

Comment: @JohnB I provided two links. 1: Show an image of the entire site layout which is my goal. The 2nd is a link to my live site. I am trying to get the footer of the site layout to look like the one on my live site.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Kyle, please let me know if this works? http://jsfiddle.net/GFec3/

Comment: No, this is what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/GFec3/1/ just stuff relevant to the footer, as your question is about the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the third `<ul>` goes down is because you have an extra 1px of border (`border-right: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;`).

The way you did it was having a 900px container and divide it into 3 columns. That's correct.
But once you added an extra `border-right: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;`, the column width become 301px (300px width + 1px border = **301px**).

To solve this, either you make change the container size into 903px. Or you reduce the width size into 299px.

---

The other problem about

> the footer dotted lines show past the layout.

Be careful with `padding`. When you add padding inside a div. It is counted as extra width.

Some part of your CSS for `<ul>` is:

```
    width:902px;
    padding:20px;
```

The total width is `902px (width) + 20px (left padding) + 20px (right padding) = **942px**`

To fix this, you change the `padding` at your `<ul>` by using `padding:20px 0px;`. The **first** value represents top & bottom padding, the **second** value represents left & right padding.

Comment: thank you very much sorry for the late response. I passed out late night was very tired. But I tried it this morning and all was fine. Also thank you for the help comments that was very helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions

increase width of the content

```
.content {
  width: 903px; 
}
```

or remove border of the last ul in content

```
.content ul:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I increased the width to 903 but it didn't fix it. Also the dotted line for the top and bottom of the footer are hanging past the site's width. Any other suggestions thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

add this css

```
.content {
    padding:20px 0;
}

#footer ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  width: 275px;
  height:120px;
}
```

also add a class to last `ul` and add this

```
.last {
   border:none;
}
```

better do this as suggested by Emrah

```
.content ul:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your columns don't fit enough in a parent. Set `style="border:none;"` for the last column.

Comment: I increased the width to 903 but it didn't fix it. Also the dotted line for the top and bottom of the footer are hanging past the site's width. Any other suggestions thank you!!

Comment: Whar browser do you use. For now I can say, that in FF and Chrome columns look fine with parent width 903px;

Comment: .content padding makes div wider, so top and bottom borders are 903 + 20 + 20 px wide long. Make .content `padding: 20px 0;`